# Conditional Page Layout/fields depending on the value(s) of a Pick-List?

Tags: visualforce

I have used the following code to successfully create "Dynamic VF pages", but need to alter it to handle multiple cases:

- I created a new pick-list field called "Workorder_Type__c" which could be one of four values (Voice, Data, Elan, Hosted)
- When the VF edit page is opened, I need the code to look at the value of "Workorder_Type__c" and display appropriate fields
- Currently, the code below is triggered by a "change" in the "Opp Stage"

Question: How do I alter the section `<apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="thePageBlock" status="status"/>` so that it doesn't require me to change the Stage, but just looks at the pick-list value (before the page loads) and displays the correct fields?

```
    <apex:page standardController="Opportunity" sidebar="false">
    <apex:sectionHeader title="Edit Opportunity" subtitle="{!opportunity.name}"/>
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Edit Opportunity" id="thePageBlock" mode="edit">
            <apex:pageMessages />
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
                <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}"/>                
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:actionRegion >
                <apex:pageBlockSection title="Basic Information" columns="1">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.name}"/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.ownerId}"/>
                    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                        <apex:outputLabel value="Stage"/>
                        <apex:outputPanel >
                            <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.stageName}">
                                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="thePageBlock"
                                                    status="status"/>
                            </apex:inputField>
                            <apex:actionStatus startText="applying value..." id="status"/>
                        </apex:outputPanel>
                    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.amount}"/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.closedate}"/>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
            </apex:actionRegion>
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Closed Lost Information" columns="1"
                                   rendered="{!opportunity.stageName == 'Closed Lost'}">
                <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.competitor__c}"  required="true"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Reason_Lost__c}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove all actionsupport/actions

```
<apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="thePageBlock"

                                                status="status"/>
```

and

```
<apex:actionStatus startText="applying value..." id="status"/>
```

The VF page gets the record info based on the ID in the URL, if the oppty stage = Closed Lost, the section will render else it will not

Comment: Rao, how do I create the CASE statement on this section to handle my four values and four page laouts?: 

rendered="{!opportunity.Workorder_Type__c== '(Voice, OR Data, OR Elan, OR Hosted)'}">